# Okular and Evince do not find pdf hyperlinks correctly

Tags: hyperref, pdf, evince, okular

Okular, Evince and AdobeReader5 do not hit the referenced hyperlink marks. These applications go repeatedly, reliably, one page too far in document when clicking a link. AdobeReader9, FoxitReader and ePDFViewer do the Job perfectly. Does this problem only appear using PDFLaTeX-generated documents or does it lie in the ViewerSofware?

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC - frame1/page1}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section One - this link should refer to frame2/page2}
\begin{frame}Section One - frame2/page2\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection One One - this link should refer to frame3/page3}
\begin{frame}Subsection One One - frame3/page3\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection One One, frame4/page4\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection One One, frame5/page5\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection One Two this link should refer to frame6/page6}
\begin{frame}Subsection One Two - frame6/page6\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection One Two - frame7/page7\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection One Two - frame8/page8\end{frame}

\section{Section Two - this link should refer to frame9/page9}
\begin{frame}Section Two - frame9/page9\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection Two One - this link should refer to frame10/page10}
\begin{frame}Subsection Two One - frame10/page10\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection Two One - frame11/page11\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection Two One - frame12/page12\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection Two One - this link should refer to frame13/page13}
\begin{frame}Subsection Two Two - frame13/page13\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection Two Two - frame14/page14\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection Two Two - frame15/page15\end{frame}

\section{Section Three - this link should refer to frame16/page16}
\subsection{Subsection Three One - this link should refer to frame16/page16}
\begin{frame}Subsection Three One - frame16/page16\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection Three One - frame17/page17\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Subsection Three One - frame18/page18\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Which version of software do you use? I'm using pdfTeX-1.40.15, beamer 3.36, and evince 3.14.2 under Gentoo Linux and it works as expected.
Adobe Reader 5 has been outdated for years (I think it was released around 2000...)
Edit: Maybe you have to run pdflatex twice to get the references right?!?